# tcsh, Command not found

Tags: tcsh

I have tried to run an executable 'crcor' with the command

```
ben-Aspire-S3-391:/usr/local/src/runz% /usr/local/src/runz/crcor
/usr/local/src/runz/crcor: Command not found.
```

I have successfully run the code on another machine but am unable to reproduce the results on this machine.

On both machines,
`which sh` returns `/bin/sh`

however
`echo $shell` returns `/bin/tcsh` on the working machine
and `/usr/bin/tcsh` on the not working machine.

Any tips on how to diagnose the difference between the two to help me get this running would be great.

Edit1:crcor is an executable that links to a fortran code
Edit2: edited for spelling, '/usr/bin/tsch' --> '/usr/bin/tcsh'

Solution: Installing 32-bit libraries on my system (64-bit) has solved the issue. 'ldd' command on the working version revealed that it was recognised as a dynamic executable but on the not-working version it wasn't recognised as a dynamic executeable. Specifically ia32-libs was installed.

Comment: Is `crcor` a shell script? What is its first line? Is `/usr/bin/tsch` a typo for `/usr/bin/tcsh`, or is it really spelled that way?

Comment: The way to indicate that you've solved a problem is to accept an answer, not to add "[Solved]" to the title. It's perfectly ok to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Installing 32-bit libraries on my system (64-bit) has solved the issue. 'ldd' command on the working version revealed that it was recognised as a dynamic executable but on the not-working version it wasn't recognised as a dynamic executeable. Specifically ia32-libs was installed.